# Xamarin forms content page scroll to stacklayout on Initialization

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to scroll to a stacklayout automatically when a content page initializes?

Comment: Within a ScrollView?

Comment: Do you mean scrolling an **UIElement** in `Stacklayout` which that `StackLayout` inside a `ScrollView` ?

Comment: No. I have a `Stacklayout` in a `Stacklayout` where both are inside a `ScrollView `. I need to scroll automatically into the seccond `Stacklayout`when the page initializes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add scroll View to your layout. Assume you have a stacklayout with name as below:

```
<ScrollView x:Name="myscrollview">
   .
   .
   .
   <StackLayout x:Name="teststack">
   </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Then you scroll to the element `teststack` using `ScrollToAsync` method of ScrollView as below:

```
await myscrollview.ScrollToAsync((StackLayout)teststack, ScrollToPosition.Start, true);
```

Comment: Hi Thank you, I also have a listview Inside a scrollview. I know its not a good method but there are more other details i need to display in the scrollview along with the listview. But the listview displays an an empty area everythime it is loaded. What could be done for this?

Comment: I had the same problem. For this put the listview in a stacklayout and set a constant height to the stacklayout. @anslemarnolda

Comment: but then the scrolling wont work in the listview unless i hold the screen with another finger and scroll. Did u fix this?

Comment: Try putting the `StackLayout` inside a `Grid`